# MVC FormCollection HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post

I am sending form values to a controller via FormCollection, I also pass in a button as a string, the controller uses this to determine which button has been clicked within the form.

It all works fine in development but when deployed it does not work. It seems that either the  button value is not getting  to the controller or its the form collection.

I have included the view code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateExceptionsList", "Exceptions", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "exceptionsForm" }))
{
   @*<input type="submit" id="SubmitButton" value="Update Selected"   />*@
    <button name="button" value="UpdateSelected" id="UpdateSelected"  onclick="processUpdate(this)" >Update Selected</button>
     <button name="button" value="ExportCsv" onclick="processExportCsv(this)">Export Csv</button>
      <button name="button" value="CancelSelected" id="CancelSelected" onclick="processdownload(this)">Cancel Selected  </button>
      <button name="button" value="RetrySelected" id="RetrySelected" onclick="processretry(this)">Retry Selected  </button>
      @Html.Hidden("RedirectTo", Url.Action("NoExceptionsExist","Exceptions"))

}
```

and the corresponding controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateExceptionsList(FormCollection result, string button)
{
    bool createCsv = false;
    bool cancelSelected = false;
    bool retrySelected = false;
    if (button == "ExportCsv")
    {
        createCsv = true;
    }
    else if(button == "CancelSelected")
    {
        cancelSelected = true;
    }
    else if (button == "RetrySelected")
    {
        retrySelected = true;
    }
}
```

Am i missing some configuration in IIS, as it all works fine in Visual Studio. 
Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using direct `button` parameter use it with `FormCollection` i.e.

```
if (result["button"] == "ExportCsv") {
   // your logic.
}
```

This will fix your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this? Why don't you create a separate action for each button?

Comment: I have to call in the same controller, there are values within the form that dictate this

Comment: They can all be in the same controller, but different actions. You can do an ajax post for each button.